# How to include Google Analytics in preact

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, preact

Please let me know how to include google analytics in `preact`? I found someone did in `react` as follow

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.ga = window.ga || function() { (ga.q = ga.q || []).push(arguments)  }; ga.l = +new Date;
    const account = this.props.account;
    // const scriptProtocol = ("https:" === document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www");
    const scriptSrc = `//google-analytics.com/analytics.js`;
    jQuery.getScript(scriptSrc, () => {
      // Track Route changes
      ga("create", account, "auto");
      if(this.props.history) {
        this.props.history.listen((newLocation) => {
          ga("send", "pageview", newLocation.pathname);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

But problem is this person used `jQuery` in the above code which goes `undefined`. Please let me know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [react-ga](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/) dependency to achieve this.

As mentioned in that project's documentation: add it as a dependency with `npm install react-ga --save`  (if you're using npm, for example), then simply add this code to your main component:

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000-01');
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

[react-ga](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/) also has function calls to do the same you would do with your jQuery approach, like sending pageviews and other data to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

For working with jquery follow this

try installing `npm install jquery`

then import jquery as following

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
```

Other method for adding google analytics is add the following code which dose't require jquery

```
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', '***YOUR ID HERE****', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```